# Struct implementation advice

Tags: c, struct

I have some very very basic idea what a **struct** is and how it works.

My goal is to create an attendance-program using structure:

- input: worker, time he came to work, time he left - he can leave and come multiple times (lunch break for example)
- output: how many hours did each the longest worker work and who was he.

For example:

```
+ 8:00:00 100

+ 8:50:00 105

- 9:30:00 100

- 18:20:00 105

- 19:00:00 100

- 17:00:00 100

+ 18:00:00 100

+ 9:00:00 200

+ 10:00:00 100

- 15:00:00 200
```

Output:

```
Longest work time: 9:30:00 

Longest workers: 100, 105
```

My original idea was to use struct this way:

```
typedef struct work {
    int *arrivals;
    int *departures;
    int *result;
} WORK;
WORK 66, 100, 105, 200;
```

Then I would dynamically allocate memories for arrivals and departures, sort them and compare elements of `arrival[i]` and `departure[i]`.

The problem with this is that the number of elements (workers) may be varying and you cannot dynamically add new elements into structures.

So how can I change the structure to suit my needs?

Comment: what is arrivals and departures? you could make it a linked list of some sort so it is a variable size

Comment: arrivals and departures are pointers to arrays that I will later malloc. Inside those arrays I will store the times of their departures/arrivals, sort it and then calculate how long they worked.

Comment: A single linked list to save a variable number of departures and arrivals: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Answer (score 2):

If the number of workers is not known ahead of time, but once known will be fixed, dynamically allocate an array of `WORK`s.  This would be done in exactly the same way you are doing `arrival`s, except you'd use you `work` struct instead of the `time`struct.

If the number will change over time, you can either use `realloc` to do the above but change its size when needed, or use a more dynamic structure (like a linked list).  `realloc` is similar to `malloc`, except that it takes a pointer & a new size, and modifies the thing it points to (possibly moving it) to make it the new size.  For a linked list, you need to (at least) add a field to your `struct` which is a pointer to that same kind of `struct`, which is used to tell you where the next item in the list is.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show me how such a struct would look like? Still struggling with structs in general.

Comment: Even if you do not know the number of workers, Scott's method still works. Say for example you expect to have `20` workers. What I would do to preserve flexibility (e.g. you end up with 60 workers) is to allocate `20` pointers to a workers struct (say containing `name` (whatever else, e.g. `id`,...) and then a dynamic array(s) that hold `in/out` time for that worker. You can allocate more space for time `in/out` as needed. In both cases, initialize all `pointer/array` values to `0`. That way you can iterate over workers and time while `!NULL` or `!0` (time worked can't be `0` anyway)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there are a number of ways to approach this problem. The primary consideration boils down to **How do I want to handle my struct?, an array of structs? or an array of pointers to struct?**. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

The biggest disadvantage of choosing an **array of structs** is you will bear the burden of keeping track of all of the indexes associated with the array, as well as the time array within each struct. Choosing an **array of pointers to struct** helps a bit by allowing you to initialize a block of pointers to `NULL`. As you add a worker, instead of `NULL`, you have an address in the pointer. This allows you to iterate through your array of pointers with a simple `while (!NULL) {do stuff...}`

The second little twist comes in using `calloc` instead of `malloc`. By using `calloc`, you initialize the memory allocated to `zero/NULL`. This can apply equally to **an array of structs** or **an array of pointers to struct**. This provides the ability to use the `while (!NULL) {do stuff...}` iteration. (the indexing is a bit more involved with an **array of structs**)

The remainder of the code should be fairly readable and straight forward. Here, we define an `INITWKR` value of `25` to allocate in initial block of pointers to struct. The struct is defined with several additional members useful in your **worker with the most time** calculations. In fact, aside from keeping track of the `time in/time out`, there is no reason to store an array of values within each worker's struct. In the code, while the (minutes worked for each shift) is stored in the `time` array in each struct, the actual `date/time` code is omitted. That would just clutter the logic for purposes of the example.

As each new worker is entered, a new struct is allocated for him and the pointer value is stored in the array of pointers to struct. The input loop checks whether that name already exists (has a struct), if so, then additional time is added and no new struct allocation is needed. During each input iteration, you will need to check whether you have exhausted your allocated pointers or allocated time array and `realloc` as needed. I have placed comments in the code and included the necessary test variables, but omitted the reallocation code to prevent cluttering the worker/time logic.

When the input loop is completed (just hit `[enter]` instead of providing input), all worker **times worked** are printed and the worker with the **most time is shown.** The program then takes care to free all dynamically allocated memory and then exits.

Take a look, the code is commented fairly well. If you get stuck, just drop a comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INITWKR 25

typedef struct {
    char *name;         /* worker name      */
    int *time;          /* time array (min) */  /* optional     */
    unsigned entries;   /* entries in time  */
    unsigned size;      /* allocated size   */  /* realloc test */
    unsigned total;     /* total time (min) */
} worker;

int main () {

    char *name = NULL;  /* name input       */
    int tio = 0;        /* time input       */
    int idx = 0;        /* workers index    */
    int idxmax = 0;     /* index max time   */
    int tdx = 0;        /* time index       */
    int tmax = 0;       /* max worker time  */
    char exist = 0;     /* wkr exists flag  */
    int wkrsz = INITWKR;/* num of wkr ptrs  */

    /* create INITWKR pointers to struct (initialize NULL) */
    worker **wkrs = calloc (INITWKR, sizeof (*wkrs));

    printf ("\nPunch the clock, enter name & minutes worked ([enter] alone to end)\n");

    /* input loop, read name and minutes worked for each shift */
    while (printf ("\n  name: ") && scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &name) >= 1 &&
            printf ("  time: ") && scanf ("%d%*c", &tio) >= 1 )
    {
        idx = 0;            /* reset loop vars  */
        exist = 0;

        while (wkrs[idx])   /* check each filled worker */
        {
            /* check if already has struct  */
            if (strcmp (wkrs[idx]->name, name) == 0) {
                exist = 1;
                break;
            }
            idx++;          /* idx points to first avail pointer at end */
        }
        /* if (idx >= INITWKR - 1) reallocate poiner array */

        if (!exist) {
            /* add new worker */
            wkrs[idx] = malloc (sizeof (**wkrs));
            wkrs[idx]-> name = strdup (name);
            wkrs[idx]-> time = calloc (INITWKR, sizeof (int));
            wkrs[idx]-> entries = 0;
            wkrs[idx]-> size = INITWKR;
            wkrs[idx]-> total = 0;
        }

        /* add time to worker */
        tdx = 0;
        while ((wkrs[idx]-> time)[tdx])
            tdx++;
        /* if (tdx >= wkrs[idx]-> size - 1) reallocate wkrs[idx]-> time, increment size */
        (wkrs[idx]-> time)[tdx] = tio;
        wkrs[idx]-> entries++;
        wkrs[idx]-> total += tio;
        if (wkrs[idx]-> total > tmax) {
            tmax = wkrs[idx]-> total;
            idxmax = idx;
        }
    }

    if (name) free (name);  /* free memory allocated by scanf    */

    printf ("\nWorker Time Summary:\n\n");

    idx = 0;
    while (wkrs[idx]) {     /* output worker name/time & max    */
        if (idx == idxmax)
            printf ("  Worker[%2d] : %-24s   time: %d  (max time)\n", idx, wkrs[idx]->name, wkrs[idx]->total);
        else
            printf ("  Worker[%2d] : %-24s   time: %d\n", idx, wkrs[idx]->name, wkrs[idx]->total);
        idx++;
    }
    printf ("\n");

    idx = 0;
    while (wkrs[idx]) {     /* free dynamically allocated mem   */
        if (wkrs[idx]->name) free (wkrs[idx]->name);
        if (wkrs[idx]->time) free (wkrs[idx]->time);
        if (wkrs[idx]) free (wkrs[idx++]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**example:**

```
$ ./bin/workers

Punch the clock, enter name & minutes worked ([enter] alone to end)

  name: JD Clark
  time: 38

  name: Mike Wu
  time: 34

  name: JD Clark
  time: 39

  name: Mike Wu
  time: 53

  name: JD Clark
  time: 64

  name: Tim Taylor
  time: 55

  name:

Worker Time Summary:

  Worker[ 0] : JD Clark                   time: 141  (max time)
  Worker[ 1] : Mike Wu                    time: 87
  Worker[ 2] : Tim Taylor                 time: 55
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a little code to show you how would this work. Idea is to have dynamic arrays for both `workers` and `arrivals`/`departures`.

If you know how to dynamically allocate a memory for some array `a` for example:

```
int *a;
a = (int*) malloc(100*sizeof(int));
```

Then you know how to do it with `struct`s:

```
struct s_name *my_s; // s_name is some random name of structure
my_s = (s_name*) malloc(100*sizeof(s_name));
```

And therefore you know how to allocate memory for some array inside a structure.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int h, m, s; // hour, minutes, seconds
} time;

typedef struct {
  time *arrival;
  time *departure;
  time result;

  int n_of_arrivals; // to keep track how many we have
  int n_of_departures;

} work;

work *workers;

int main(void) {
  int N;

  printf("How many entries do you have?\n> ");
  scanf("%d", &N);

  // initially create space for 100 workers
  workers = (work*) malloc(100*sizeof(work));
  int number_of_workers = 100;

  for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
    char event; // this is '+' or '-'
    int h, m, s, id;

    scanf(" %c %d:%d:%d%d", &event, &h, &m, &s, &id);

    // last position where we can put our worker is number_of_workers - 1
    if (id > number_of_workers - 1) {
      number_of_workers = id + 1;
      // realloc memory for storing workers
      workers = (work*) realloc(workers, number_of_workers*sizeof(work));
    }

    if (event == '+') {
      // add 1 to amount of arrivals
      workers[id].n_of_arrivals += 1;

      int len = workers[id].n_of_arrivals;

      // realloc memory for keeping arrivals of worker
      workers[id].arrival = (time*) realloc(workers[id].arrival, len*sizeof(time));

      // finally store new time
      time *arrival = workers[id].arrival;
      arrival[len - 1].h = h;
      arrival[len - 1].m = m;
      arrival[len - 1].s = s;
    } else {
      // this is the same as for adding arrivals
      workers[id].n_of_departures += 1;
      int len = workers[id].n_of_departures;
      workers[id].departure = (time*) realloc(workers[id].departure, len*sizeof(time));
      time *departure = workers[id].departure;
      departure[len - 1].h = h;
      departure[len - 1].m = m;
      departure[len - 1].s = s;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_workers; i++) {
    // skip worker who doesn't have track of any arrivalls or depratures
    if (!workers[i].n_of_arrivals && !workers[i].n_of_departures)
      continue;

    printf("Worker %d:\n", i);

    // print nicely arrivals
    if (workers[i].n_of_arrivals) {
      int len = workers[i].n_of_arrivals;
      printf("Arrivals:\n");
      for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
        printf("%d:%d:%d\n", workers[i].arrival[k].h, workers[i].arrival[k].m, workers[i].arrival[k].s);
    }

    // // print nicely depratures
    if(workers[i].n_of_departures) {
      int len = workers[i].n_of_departures;
      printf("Departures:\n");
      for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
        printf("%d:%d:%d\n", workers[i].departure[k].h, workers[i].departure[k].m, workers[i].departure[k].s);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I didn't wrote an algorithm for calculating the result. I will leave that to you. :)